# Using WebSockets for multiplayer HTML5 games development. What to choose, Node.js, or Ratchet, or other?

Tags: html, node.js, cakephp, ratchet

I made some research before asking this question but I couldn't find a concrete answer for my situation. I'm still new to WebSockets and games development, so I may not be able to explain some parts very well and if that's the case please tell me so I can try to explain it better.

I'm currently developing a Web application using CakePHP, which will provide several kinds of HTML5 multiplayer games. On some situations those games will need to send data to a database. The problem is, I want to use Node.js to implement the game server side logic, but I'm not sure if I'll be able to pass data to the database. I think the best approach would be sending the data from Node.js to a PHP action that will then store it on the database, but I also don't know if that will be possible.

I found something about this [DNode](http://bergie.iki.fi/blog/dnode-make_php_and_node-js_talk_to_each_other/) thing, but I'm not sure if this is the answer for my problem and besides that it seems to be in beta version, what I would like to avoid.

As an alternative, I thought about using [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/) to implement the games server side logic. At least I know that I would be able to make it communicate with my application, but since I can't find any reference to it on games development I'm not sure if it's a good idea.

I don't know about any other frameworks, so if I have better options than those two, please tell me :)

Please give me your opinions. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I faced a similar problem a year ago trying to develop an online multiplayer game. I ended up using Node.js for the server and Socket.io for the Websockets

If you're new to Node.js I recommend you to read first this brief and good basic tutorial:

http://www.nodebeginner.org/

I use node.js everyday and I really find it very useful and productive.
Once you're done reading the basics read this nice tutorial of developing multiplayer html5 games with node and sockets:
http://smus.com/multiplayer-html5-games-with-node/

There is a link to an open source game at the end that might be helpful to you.

And you can check the socket.io docs here: http://socket.io/

Hope it helps so you can get started. That's the hardest part.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think I understand now better how Node.js works. From what I understood I can also connect to a database with Node and this way I won't need to communicate with my PHP application to request data from it, right?

Comment: That's right. You can have a direct connection to a database from Node.js

Comment: Does node.js work only on VPS servers ? will it not get installed on a shared hosting.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered Node.js + Lightstreamer instead of socket.io? Simone Fabiano recently issued [an apple-to-apple data broadcasting comparison with socket.io](http://blog.lightstreamer.com/2013/05/benchmarking-socketio-vs-lightstreamer.html) (messages generated on the server side and sent to over 4 thousand clients, ran over two Amazon EC2 Machines) and it proved to be able to scale better than plain websockets with socket.io in CPU usage, data latency, and bandwidth consumption, with some other useful features to improve the overall performance.

Specifically, Lightstreamer can be used with great benefits for any multiplayer games: see also this article ([Optimizing Multiplayer 3D Game Synchronization Over the Web](http://blog.lightstreamer.com/2013/10/optimizing-multiplayer-3d-game.html)). You can walk through an online demo of a simple multiplayer 3D world in which Lightstreamer has been integrated for real-time synchronization. The demo allows you to tweak each parameter of the scenario and simulate any flavor of data delivery, while checking the actual bandwidth consumption.

Full source code both of the benchmarking kit and the demo are available for free on GitHub.

[full disclosure: I work for Lightstreamer]